# How do I mount an iPhone X in the cockpit to record flights, as a student pilot?

Tags: cell-phone, camera

I'm a student pilot and would like to mount my iPhone X in the cockpit to record my flights. Don't want to get an extra GoPro. However all the mounts I've seen online are designed for iPhone 6 or lower, and the RAM mount seems slightly troublesome to set up, in an aircraft that I'm only spending two hours in every day (and that too not the same aircraft every day).
Any suggestions as to how I can mount my phone? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What are you planning to record? Views out the window? Of the panel? Of  yourself? Audio too?

Answer (score 1):

if you were using one aircraft you could get an adhesive mount and then buy a mount that has the adhesive side and a phone mount, but since that is not the case you could try using a suction cup. i have done it a few times, it worked out OK for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the bean-bag kind of mounts to sit above the panel that have a clip to hold the phone on its sides.  They have non-slip bottom and weighted corners. I first saw these in use with portable GPSs like a Garmin. They work well in a car.  Example [https://www.amazon.com/ChargerCity-NonSlip-Smartphone-Beanbag-Friction/dp/B014VWM1F4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B014VWM1F4)

I searched for "Beanbag Friction Mount" and then a phone type to find this one.  The beanbag base and the arm ending with a ball look just like the base for my GPS.

Edit: This kind might also work well and be more stable while maneuvering  [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01N210GDQ/ref=sspa_dk_detail_1?psc=1&pd_rd_i=B01N210GDQ&pd_rd_wg=wcjC9&pd_rd_r=QR09DADY9Z9CGFH07G7W&pd_rd_w=Txnpy&smid=APMMY5ZET54AV](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01N210GDQ)

Comment: I can't see either of these faring well at all in a light aircraft